# PHP: Access Method in sub-class

Tags: php, class, methods

I want to know how to access a method i  a sub-class of a class when I'm in another sub-class of that same class... 
For example:

```
class foo {

}

class bar extends foo {
    public function something() {
        //do something here
    }
}

class soap extends foo {
    $this->something();   //This is the method I wanna call...
}
```

As you can see I wanna access a subclass's method from another sub class.
How do I do this in PHP?

Comment: @Federico it can be any method... I just wanna know how to access the method in bar from any other subclass

Comment: your soap class has to extend the foo class.

Comment: Unless `bar::something()` is static, then you'll need to have an *instance* of `bar` to be able to call `something()`.  `soap` and `bar` have *nothing* to do with each other.  The fact that they share the same parent class has no meaning.

Comment: @Federico.. If I run it that way It gives me "Method does not exist" error...

Comment: Why not just extend soap from bar instead of foo?

Comment: @RocketHazmat... So do you think it's wiser to set the something() method in the parent class?

Comment: Depending on the domain specifics, it might as well be better to inject an instance of `bar` into `soap`

Comment: @odannyc: That would be a valid solution to this, yes.  It depends on what that method does and how `bar` (and `soap`) are using it, but that should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it directly, but only *if* `soap` is also a subclass of `bar`:

```
class soap extends bar {
    public function someFunction() 
    {
        $this->something();   // This will work
    }
}
```

If it's *not*, you still have an option: obtain an instance of `bar` and then call the method on it:

```
class soap extends foo {
    public function someFunction(bar $bar) 
    {
        $bar->something();   // This will also work
    }
}
```

Barring that, there's not much else you can do. Since `bar` is not in `soap`'s inheritance chain, there is no way to reference `something` using only `$this` from within any of `soap`'s methods.

Comment: That second way worked, throwing in the instance into the method. Thanks!